# Can't add the item to the Protractor e2e test

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, button, protractor

I have one ionic menu button, that I can't add to the protractor e2e tests. I tried by element, by xpath, by css, everything. It always gets an error.

This is the button:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGImS.png)

this is what I tried:

```
 //element(by.css('ion-header button')).click(); 
//element(by.xpath('/html/body/ion-app/ng-component/ion-nav/page-home-tutor/ion-header/ion-header/ion-navbar/button[1]')).click();
```

And other things, but it seems that I can't connect the button or make the button to be clicked.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
Browser.actions().mouseMove($('ion-header button')).mouseDown().mouseUp().perform;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).